# Touch listener not working in RecyclerView + ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

My current layout has a `CoordinatorLayout`, in which I've a `TabLayout` connected to a `ViewPager2`. Within ViewPager, I have a couple of tabs of `RecyclerView`.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout ... ">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar ... />
            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                ...
                app:tabMode="scrollable" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    
    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        ...
        android:clickable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My image grid (RecyclerView) uses a `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener` to implement drag select functionality via this [library](https://github.com/afollestad/drag-select-recyclerview).

**Issue:** Drag selection works fine when I use the RecyclerView without the ViewPager2, but as soon as I put the RecyclerView fragment within the view pager, it's swipe gesture starts interfering with the RecyclerView's touch listener.

To confirm the same, I did `viewPager.setIsUserInputEnabled(false)` and the drag selection started working but then the view pager swipe no longer works.

Comment: Can you disable the viewPager swiping whenever drag-swiping is taking place? And then re-enable it after, of course.

Comment: @GavinWright I thought about the same, but for the drag select lib there is only an activation function and nothing for deactivation (which actually makes sense since you drag & select items and you're done!) . Currently I'm experimenting with `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` motion events.